# clip-path with video html

Tags: reactjs, svg, safari, clip-path

I have an issue with clip-path property with video tag in Safari browser. In chrome and firefox, clip-path with video works fine. Actually Saffary should support it maybe my code has some other bugs. Please advise me something to make it works in Safari. Thank you!

```
<video loop width="852" height="480" autoplay class="svg-clipped-text">
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/323909/bouncyballs.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<svg height="0" width="0">
  <clipPath id="svgTextPath">
     <text x="20" y="200" textLength="800px" lengthAdjust="spacing" font-family="Luckiest Guy" font-size="210px">
       BOUNCE
     </text>
   </clipPath>
</svg>
<br />
<a href="https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/" title="Sara Soueidan is a freelance front-end Web developer, author and speaker from Lebanon." >Sara Soueidan's Excellent SVG Clipping Article</a>
<p>Safari/Edge/IE no joy :(</p>

    video{
  display:block;
  margin:20px auto;
}
.svg-clipped-text {
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgTextPath);
    clip-path: url(#svgTextPath);
}


a{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top: -200px;
}
p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/DeeDee23/pen/vKVwzd)

try to play around [here](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: Safari simply doesn't support this.

Comment: @RobertLongson Do you know any other solutions to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2):

You cant use clip-path on video tag in Safari browser as it is doesn't render shape. Instead of it use clip-path on parent block and it will work on Safari.

Comment: Also Safary have bug when scale svg in browser by (ctr +/-).